# MatDialog not opening in IE 11

Tags: angular, angular-material

All of that dialogs in my project are not opening in IE11 for my deployed code but work fine on my local running in IE. All of them follow the same code.

component.html

```
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" class="accent" type="button" (click)="openNewCaseModal()" [disabled]="disableSubmit">{{ 'CASES.createCase' | translate }}</button>
```

component.ts

```
  openNewCaseModal(row) 

const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CaseComponent, {
  width: '75%',
  data: this.caseData
});
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  if (result === 'submitted') {
    this.caseCreated.emit();
    this.snackbar.open('Case Created', '', { duration: 2000, verticalPosition: 'top' } );
  } else if (result === 'error submitted') {
    this.snackbar.open('Error Creating Case. Please Try Again.', '', { duration: 2000, verticalPosition: 'top' });
  }
});
```

}

dialog.component.ts

```
constructor(
 private caseService: CasesService,
 private sidebarService: SidebarService,
 private dialog: MatDialogRef<CaseComponent>,
 private fb: FormBuilder,
 private snackbar: MatSnackBar,
 @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
}
```

My Error in IE console when I try to open the Dialog.

> Error: StaticInjectorError[e ->
>   function(){this.role="dialog",this.panelClass="",this.hasBackdrop=!0,this.backdropClass="",this.disableClose=!1,this.width="",this.height="",this.maxWidth="80vw",this.data=null,this.ariaDescribedBy=null,this.ariaLabel=null,this.autoFocus=!0,this.restoreFocus=!0,this.closeOnNavigation=!0}]:
>
> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[e ->
>   function(){this.role="dialog",this.panelClass="",this.hasBackdrop=!0,this.backdropClass="",this.disableClose=!1,this.width="",this.height="",this.maxWidth="80vw",this.data=null,this.ariaDescribedBy=null,this.ariaLabel=null,this.autoFocus=!0,this.restoreFocus=!0,this.closeOnNavigation=!0}]:
>
> NullInjectorError: No provider for
>   function(){this.role="dialog",this.panelClass="",this.hasBackdrop=!0,this.backdropClass="",this.disableClose=!1,this.width="",this.height="",this.maxWidth="80vw",this.data=null,this.ariaDescribedBy=null,this.ariaLabel=null,this.autoFocus=!0,this.restoreFocus=!0,this.closeOnNavigation=!0}!

It looks like these errors are referring to the this.dialog.open() function I am calling to open the dialog. Also the fact that I can only reproduce it in my deployed code is make it difficult to debug.

Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you include ie specific polyfills?

Comment: yeah polyfills are included

Comment: Can you setup minimal github repo with that issue so we can test it? It might related to angular, material or cli version

Comment: Well I am in the classic my code runs fine locally situation. Locally on IE dialogs are opening fine but the deployed project is throwing those errors and not opening the dialog. Also deployed code is working fine in all other browsers

Comment: Have you tried to run built version locally?

Comment: What I am running locally is up to date with what has been deployed if that is what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I mean what if you try those built-artefacts that Angular Cli compiled after `ng build --prod`

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I was having trouble running a build from the dist. I was able to reproduce the error from the build. So something happening in the build process potentially. Thanks for the direction

Comment: I can ask you again `Can you setup minimal github repo with that issue so we can test it?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was missing pollyfils in the pollyfills.ts file.

I was missing the below pollyfill imports:

- import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
- import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

My guess is that in the error:

> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[e ->
>   function(){this.role="dialog",this.panelClass="",this.hasBackdrop=!0,this.backdropClass="",this.disableClose=!1,this.width="",this.height="",this.maxWidth="80vw",this.data=null,this.ariaDescribedBy=null,this.ariaLabel=null,this.autoFocus=!0,this.restoreFocus=!0,this.closeOnNavigation=!0}]:

The (Platform: core) pieces is referring to core-js. No other indication that this is correct but the dialogs are working now.

Thank you @yurzui for the suggestions in troubleshooting the error.

Comment: We were missing the es7/reflect polyfill, but the es6/weak-map doesn't seem to be required.